# Proof of Sequence Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_n = \ln(n+1) - \ln(n)$

Consider the function $f(x) = \ln(1+ 1/x)$
As $n \to \infty$,
$\ln(1+ 1/x) \to \ln(1) = 0$

Thus as $n\to \infty$,
$a_n \to 0$
Hence the sequence is convergent.

Does this proof make mathematical sense? Are the theorems i'm using logical?

Comment: Looks good to me. You should state that you're using the continuity of $\ln$ here. Also it should be as $x \to \infty$ not as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof makes sense. The technique you used to write $\frac{(n+1)}{n}$ as $1+\frac{1}{n}$ and noting that $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is very powerful for finding limits of rational functions. Good job.

If you were writing up a proper solution, I would make it more clear how you are going from $\ln{(n+1)}-\ln{n}$ to $\ln{(1+\frac{1}{n})}$.

Comment: Disagree. Adding the new $f(x)$ is necessary to emphasise that we are using the continuity of the function $\ln$ in the answer (and this fact should be emphasised). At the very least, this fact should be emphasised somewhere. It is in no way trivial that $1 + \frac1n \to 1 \implies \ln(1 + \frac1n) \to \ln(1)$